# How to Code to Avoid Timeout in PHP

Tags: php, timeout

I have a problem with router/modem/ISP timeouts where my page will be given the blank page with timeout warnings. It seems not to be an issue on the server side, since the page will load eventually with enough time given on a different router/modem/ISP.

Let us assume that I have no other way to optimize the running time, and the page will need to run as long as it does. Is there any way to 100% preventing timeouts in client's browser? I coded in PHP.

Comment: Do you use a toaster as router or you have 23423GB of data on this page? ô.o
its 2016... there's nearly no website not loading cause of timeout... at least not with the right equipment..

Comment: Sounds like you have some issue with stuff you do in background if your script runs into a timeout. You should think about changing the architecture to an asynchronous approach which will save a lot of hassles. But if you really look for a quick and dirty solution then raise the settings in your `php.ini` file that limit the amount of time available for a script to be executed. The default value is 30 seconds. You can also try to do that in a dynamic manner using the `set_ini()` function. See it's documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: You could also use set_time_limit(int $seconds). See documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: `Let us assume that I have no other way to optimize the running time` Assuming that would be ignorant, there is always a better way.

Comment: @Twinfriends: I wish things were like that. Like I said, the receiving end is to blame, and I cannot control the receiving end, can't I? It loaded perfectly on other devices. But on certain ISPs/routers, it got timed out.

Comment: @arkascha & Michael: I, of course, checked on the set_time_limit. Like I said, it doesn't timed out on my daily use, so I assume that my server maybe took a bit time, but memory is more than enough. But it got timed out on the receiving end on other devices.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "on the receiving end on other devices". If that refers to clients running into a timeout, then sure, if your server takes 5 minutes to process some background task and does not give any sign of life in that time your browser or whatever client probably will time out. You would have to feed something to the client on a regular base, like a heart beat. But this all goes into the wrong direction, since it tries to solves symptoms instead of addressing the cause of the issue.

Comment: @ViktorKoncsek: I specifically added this clause, because I think that the timeout is purely on the connection of the receiving end that forces the timeout. I'm trying to find clues of why this timeout occur and how to avoid it. Any ideas?

Comment: @arkascha: To make it clear, I'm pretty sure it's the connection from the ISP/router/modem that limited my timeout. With the same laptop, with my home connection I could load the page after 10 seconds with ease. But when I visited another place, it timed me out after 5 seconds. Very weird.

Comment: And what do you mean by "the connection from the ISP/router/modem"? If you refer to your connection between http client and http server being routed, then be assured that none of the devices in between that relays your connection has any concept of a time out or even of any protocol. Those work on lower protocol levels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a resource-extensive script, consider increasing your timeout limit using the [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/set_time_limit) function.

`set_time_limit(60); // 60 seconds`

If you hate your server, you can even use `0`for no limit:

`set_time_limit(0); // to stop this, you would need to restart your web server`

If you want your script to continue working **even** if the request is aborted such as when the web browser is closed by the user, you may be interested to use [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/ignore_user_abort).

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
ignore_user_abort(true);
echo 'Hello world! Wait for it...';
sleep(30);
file_put_contents('testing.txt','Even if you closed your browser, this file will be created.');
echo 'Thanks for waiting!';
?>
```

### Reminder

Use of these functions may **NOT** be a good practice. Consider revising your script. If this is a script that will be accessed by multiple users, this could crash your server.